# CSS Specificity: ID overwritten by class + element

Tags: css, css-specificity

So, my id selector with a colour !important is being overwritten by a simple .class h1 selector with no !important. I am baffled and unable to find any info on this.

I know about css specificity and no matter how I look at it, I would expect the h1 to be green even without the !important.

HTML:

```
<body id='id'>
  <div class='class'>
    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.class { color: black; }
.class h1 { color: red; }
#id { color: green !important; }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TJ8tj/2/

I have tested this behaviour in latest Chrome, Safari and Firefox on OS X 10.9.1

Comment: Do not use !important

Comment: this would work if `#id` was applied to `h1` element

Comment: @James King Why not use !important? I use this to make sure I overwrite any other rules...

Comment: Its bad practice. You should write better, more specific rules if you want to overwrite other rules. What happens when you need to overwrite a rule with !important?? You cant

Comment: @JamesKing I have used it merely to emphasise my issue, as stated in the description I expected it to work without !important.

Comment: @James King: Well you can override a less specific `!important` with a more specific one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `.class h1` rule is applying a color directly to the `h1` element itself, so it will never inherit the color from `body`. The `!important` only affects the `body` element because it is the one with the ID. It does not force child elements to inherit that value. Specificity also becomes irrelevant since your selectors are targeting different elements.

In fact, the `!important` doesn't play any role in your code and so it should be removed.

Comment: Ok this clears things up a bit. Guess I'll have to rethink my workflow around this then. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The specificy is relevant only when applied to the same element.

Your rules target 3 different elements, so there is no conflict.. each element is drawn according to its own rules..

Read the docs at http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascading-order